# ATLAS via Cython vs. numpy: how is numpy faster?

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy, cython, gsl

I am programming a function in Cython which will be called many times. The majority of my code is "Cython" syntax C with the numerical operations performed using the GNU Scientific Library (GSL).

One thing that has interested me is there that is one particular operation which I am incapable of matching numpy's speed on. Please note that the performance gain here is not *that* important, rather the reason *why* numpy appears to be faster is interesting me.

The particular operation I refer to is this (the random numbers are dummy variables - I do not anticipate they make a difference):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1.,2.])
Q = np.random.random((1000))
W = np.random.random((1000,2))
b = np.random.random((1000))

Q.dot(np.cos(W.dot(x) + b))
```

Timing the last line:

```
%timeit Q.dot(np.cos(W.dot(x) + b))

10000 loops, best of 3: 27 µs per loop
```

Numpy's speed here does not surprise me particularly. What I am curious about is why my cython version is almost twice as slow. Assuming variables are similarly initialised outside of the function, I perform the calculation in cython as follows (*edit: full working example at the end of this post - removed some of the code here for tidiness*):

```
gsl_blas_dgemv(CblasNoTrans,1,W,x,1,b)

for 0 <= i < n:
    b.data[i*step] = cos(b.data[i*step])

gsl_blas_ddot(Q,b,&result)
```

Producing:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.8 µs per loop
```

When I run that part of the function in isolation.

Cython should be linked with Atlas (I am doing my testing in a notebook with `-L/usr/lib64/atlas -ltatlas` as flags after the cell magic `%%cython`), and has an -O3 optimisation flag.

My questions are as follows:

- Is my problem algorithmic? To the best of my knowledge the loop over the dot product between W and x to compute the cosine of the elements is necessary.
- Should row or column major ordering of the arrays make a significant difference in this case?
- Is numpy that much faster simply due to a more efficient back-end for these kind of operations, and if so, how does it accomplish this?
- Am I naive to think this is a good measure of performance?
- Is my Cython version simply poorly coded?

I'm very interested in learning where the speed difference comes from in this case.

**Edit 1: Complete example of cython code**

```
%%cython -lgsl -L/usr/lib64/atlas -ltatlas -lm

import Cython.Compiler.Options as CO
CO.extra_compile_args = ["-f",'-O3',"-ffast-math","-march=native"]
from libc.string cimport memcpy
from libc.math cimport cos
from cython_gsl cimport *
cimport cython

cdef gsl_vector * gsl_vector_create(double[:] v, int n):
    cdef gsl_vector *u = gsl_vector_alloc(n)
    u.data = &v[0]
    return u

cdef gsl_matrix * gsl_matrix_create(double[:,:] A, int n, int m):
    cdef gsl_matrix * B = gsl_matrix_alloc(n,m)
    B.data = &A[0,0]
    return B

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def test(double [:] x_, double[:] Q_, double[:,:] W_, double[:] b_, int d, int n):

    cdef:
        gsl_vector * x = gsl_vector_create(x_,d)
        gsl_vector * Q = gsl_vector_create(Q_,n)
        gsl_matrix * W = gsl_matrix_create(W_,n,d)
        gsl_vector * b = gsl_vector_create(b_,n)
        int i


    gsl_blas_dgemv(CblasNoTrans,1,W,x,1,b)

    cdef size_t step = b.stride
    for 0 <= i < n:
        b.data[i*step] = cos(b.data[i*step])

    cdef double result
    gsl_blas_ddot(Q,b,&result)

    return result
```

Then in python:

```
x = np.array([1.,2.])
Q = np.random.random((1000))
W = np.random.random((1000,2))
b = np.random.random((1000))

%timeit Q.dot(np.cos(W.dot(x) + b))
%timeit test(x,Q,W,b,1000,2)
```

**Edit 2**

For the sake of completeness I have also tried compiling my cython function against GSL's Cblas. This is exactly the same as the above only with the cell magic flags

```
%%cython -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

This is almost twice as slow as when compiled against atlas: `10000 loops, best of 3: 109 µs per loop`.

Comment: In this kind of question it's important to give a [mcve]. There's a few details in your Cython code where it isn't obvious what you've done - for example "where did you get `cos` from?" and "have you assigned a fixed type to any of your arrays?".

Comment: @DavidW understood, example added. I'm aware there's a tiny bit of overhead associated with copying the data over from numpy arrays but I don't think it accounts for the difference.

Comment: Thanks - that's a lot more answerable. I don't know too much about GSL, so I don't think I know the answer. It doesn't look like you're handling the GSL vectors right though: you allocate memory (`gsl_vector_alloc`), then ditch that memory to point at the already allocated numpy arrays (`u.data = &v[0]` - note the difference between copying memory and changing a pointer!), and never deallocate the memory gsl has allocated.

Comment: This is very useful in it's own regard, thankyou. As you may be able to tell, I'm not all that familiar with C. I was under the impression gsl_vector_alloc was making enough "space" in memory for me to assign the pointer from the numpy memoryview.

Comment: Which library is used by numpy? And can you see a difference if cos isn't involved?

Comment: @ead It seems (via ldd <path-to-site-packages>/numpy/core/multiarray.so) that numpy is using atlas, too. Interestingly, the difference is *even larger* after removing cos from both the numpy and gsl versions: 3.91 µs per loop for numpy and 109 µs per loop for cython/gsl.

Comment: so cython version becomes slower if you delete `cos`? because with `cos` it took only 52 for cython. I would expect the cos-evaluation to be responsible for the most of the calculation time (which is what you see with numpy). So I almost cannot believe the second value.

Comment: @ead Good point. It seems like there was some caching (or something) going on. Restarted the kernel of the notebook and it's back down to 43.1 µs.

Comment: What happens, if you just measure only `W*x+b` is there still a difference?

Comment: There is still quite a large difference, yes - it seems the other two operations might be negligible in comparison. I'm getting ~40µs in cython and ~3µs with numpy for `gsl_blas_dgemv(CblasNoTrans,1,W,x,1,b)` and `W.dot(x) + b`, respectively.

Comment: I don't think numpy uses `gsl_blas_dgemv`. if I understand it right, the `b` value is changed by `dgemv` so actually both versions of yours don't do the same thing.

Comment: @ead I am beginning to suspect the same thing. In this case, I wonder (from a point of curiosity) what numpy *is* doing and how I can replicate it. I will edit the question appropriately later.